# Counting ocurences in a list in Mathematica (with code, but not fully working)

Tags: function, count, wolfram-mathematica

My problem is this:
I have a list `list` and I want to iterate through this list and count the number of times each values from 0 to 1 occur in this in a step size `step`. I have written the following code:

```
list = {0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8, 0.17};

countingfornormal[list_, step_] := Module[{temp, num, res, i},
temp = Round[list, step];
num = {};
For[i = 0, i <= 1, i += step, {
   res = Count[temp, i];
   AppendTo[num, {i, res}];
}];
num
]
```

However, for a step size of 0.01, the output only seems to count the values up to 0.17. It's really frustrating me and I can't seem to figure out why. I have also noted that for a step size of 0.02, the output counts the values up to 0.34.

I round off at the start because originally I was using a larger list with values to around 7 places after the decimal point.

I thought maybe it was a timing issue but I'm unsure how to fix such a thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps better:

```
list = {0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8, 0.17};
b = BinCounts[list, {0, 1, 0.01}]
(*
->{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, \
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 *)
 BarChart@b
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful with the ominous "offset by one" problem. Adjust the resulting list starting point according with your expected results

Comment: That worked! And is exactly what I needed. Thanks very much, I appreciate it to no end

Comment: @user Just remember: If you are doing loops for easy tasks in Mathematica, there is a high probability that you are not aware of some pre-made features and&or functional programming ways

Comment: Ya... that has happened a few times when I've gone off and made something a lot more complicated only for a lecturer to point out another way. Thanks again.